# showing that there exists a $x \in \mathbb R^3$ such that $det(A(x))=0$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $$A: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^{3 \times 3},\ x \to A(x),$$ $A$ is Linear.

Show that there exists some  $x \in \Bbb R^3\setminus\{0\}$ with $\det\left(A(x)\right) = 0$.

I must use:

(i) The fact that $x \in \Bbb R^3\setminus\{0\}$ is connected.

(ii) Identity : $\det(-M) = (-1)^n \det(M)$ for $M \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$.

(iii) **OPTIONAL**: at some point use $\mathbb R^9$ instead of $\mathbb R^{3\times3}$.

I am well aware of the fact that $\det(A(x))=0$,  if $(a_{ij}), j = 1, 0\le i \le 3 $  and $(a_{ij}),j = 2, 0\le i \le 3$ and $(a_{ij}),j = 3, 0\le i \le 3$ are dependent.
But I am unable to use (i), (ii) and (iii) to show that.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me how to do this exercise.

Comment: **HINT** Try to use Bolzano

Comment: I don't understand, why is $A(x):=Id_{3\times 3}\forall x\in \mathbb{R}^3$ not an option?

Comment: Do you mean Bolzano-Weierstrass ? Or i did not heard about Bolzano !!Would you please explain what is Bolzano? @TitoEliatron

Comment: @LorenzoPompili My guess is that $A$ is supposed to be linear.

Comment: Am I right? Are you assuming that $A$ is linear?

Comment: You should write it then if it is an hypothesis for your problem. From what you have written, it doesn't seem this is required (but at that point the claim is false)

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Yes A is Linear i did forget to write it sorry. I will edit the question

Comment: I have edited to make some formatting change. I've also made the following mathematical change in (ii): You had written $(-M) = \cdots$. I have changed it to $\color{red}{\det}(-M) = \cdots$, which is what I suspected you mean.

Comment: @Elmagnifico in one real variable, a continuous function s.t. oin the extrema of a compact interval has a change of sign, must attain 0 somewher in the middle (roughly speaking). cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\det\bigl(A(x)\bigr)=0$ for each $x$, the statement is trivial. Otherwise, take $x\in\Bbb R^3$ such that $\det\bigl(A(x)\bigr)\ne0$. Then$$\det\bigl(A(-x)\bigr)=\det\bigl(-A(x)\bigr)=-\det\bigl(A(x)\bigr).$$On the other hand, the map $x\mapsto\det\bigl(A(x)\bigr)$ is a continuous map and therefore, since $\Bbb R^3\setminus\{0\}$ is connected, its range is a connected set. But since the range contains a number greater than $0$ and it also contains a number smaller than $0$, it must contain $0$.

Comment: How would you prove / show that $x \to det(A(x))$ is continuous ? @Jose Carlos Santos

Comment: The map $A$ is linear, and therefore continuous. The map $\det$ is polynomial, and therefore continuous. And the composition of two continuous maps is again continuous.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $f:=\det\circ A\colon \Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R$ is continuous and has $f(-x)=-f(x)$. And $\Bbb R^3\setminus\{0\}$ is still connected.